# Getting React concurrent promise wrapper to inherit returned interface object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-suspense, react-concurrent

I am experimenting with concurrent mode and suspense in React and am getting a type error when I am trying to drill some mock data from a parent component to a child component because my promise wrapper does not inherently know about the type that is getting read. The error message I am getting is:

> TS2739: Type '{ data: any; }' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'MockData': title, name, address, city

How can I have my promise wrapper know about the kind of type that is getting returned to it without explicitly saying `export const promiseWrapper = (promise: Promise<MockData>): PromiseWrapper => {...` since I want to be using this promise wrapper for other fetches that may return other interfaces? Thanks!

**sampleComponent.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import api, { MockData } from 'api/api';

const resource = api.getMockData();

const SampleComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const mockData = resource.mockData.read();
  return (
    <ChildComponent mockData={mockData} /> // type error received here
  );
};

interface ChildProps {
  mockData: MockData;
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildProps> = ({ mockData }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{mockData.title}</h1>
    <h1>{mockData.name}</h1>
    <h1>{mockData.address}</h1>
    <h1>{mockData.city}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

**api.ts:**

```
import { PromiseWrapper, promiseWrapper } from './promiseWrapper';

export interface Resource {
  [key: string]: PromiseWrapper;
}

export interface MockData {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  city: string;
}

const mockData = {
  title: 'this is a title',
  name: 'John Smith',
  address: '102 Street',
  city: 'Pittsburgh',
};

const mockDataPromise = (): Promise<{ data: MockData }> => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      data: mockData,
    });
  }, 1000);
});

const getMockData = (): Resource => {
  const getMockDataPromise = mockDataPromise();
  return {
    mockData: promiseWrapper(getMockDataPromise),
  };
};

export default {
  getMockData,
};
```

**promiseWrapper.ts:**

```
export interface PromiseWrapper {
  read(): {
    data: any;
  };
}

export const promiseWrapper = (promise: Promise<any>): PromiseWrapper => {
  let status = 'pending';
  let result: object;
  const suspender = promise.then(
    (r) => {
      status = 'success';
      result = r;
    },
    (e) => {
      status = 'error';
      result = e;
    },
  );
  return {
    // @ts-ignore
    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    read() {
      if (status === 'pending') {
        throw suspender;
      } else if (status === 'error') {
        throw result;
      } else if (status === 'success') {
        return result;
      }
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  export interface PromiseWrapper<T> {
    read(): { data: T }
  }

  export function promiseWrapper<T>(promise: Promise<{ data: T }>): PromiseWrapper<T> {
    let status = 'pending'
    let result: { data: T }
    /* rest of the function remains unchanged ... */
  }
```